# Why when updating label text and progressBar text and value the values and text are not the same?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The label start from 100 but end on 1 not on 0. Maybe ending on 1 is fine.

The progressBar is getting to 99% maybe something is wrong with calculating the percentages ?

What i want to do is:

1. Show how many messages have been downloaded out of. For example 4035/4035 then when it start the 4035 on the right will count down to 0.
2. The progrssBar to get to 100% as the text and the value. But it's getting to 98% i see the text on the progressBar 98% also the value is not getting to the end.

This is my code. In form1 constructor:

```
label8.Visible = false;
pbt.Size = new Size(216, 10);
pbt.Location = new Point(8, 312);
groupBox1.Controls.Add(pbt);
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
pbt.Text = "0%";
```

In backgroundworker dowork event

```
private int numberofallmessages = 0;
        private int countMsg = 0;

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
            PopClient.Connect("mail.bezeqint.net", 110, false);
            PopClient.Authenticate("xxxx", "yyyy",
                OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
            int messageCount = 100;//PopClient.GetMessageCount();
            numberofallmessages = messageCount;
            allMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>(messageCount);
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                allMessages.Add(PopClient.GetMessage(i));
                int nProgress = (messageCount - i) * 100 / messageCount;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress, PopClient.GetMessageCount().ToString() + "/" + i);
            }
            PopClient.Disconnect();        
        }
```

And the progressChanged event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbt.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            label8.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            label8.Visible = true;
            lstMail.Items.Add(countMsg.ToString());
        }
```

messageCount i set it to 100 in the dowork event just for testing since there are over 4000 messages but for testing i changed it to 100.

And this is a screenshot of what i see when running the program and it's getting to the end:

[image: Results]

On the left side you can see the label Downloaded emails: and see 4540/1
The 4540 is overall emails the 1 is the counter i changed to 100 for testing so it's starting from 100 and stop on 1.

Under it the progressBar the text is 98% and the value also 98 and not 100.

Comment: Try `int nProgress = (messageCount - i + 1) * 100 / messageCount;`

Comment: Might want to remove your username and password from the code too...